# Type jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory not present

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am learning Spring Data and creating a project. Project like a list of exercises, save data in MySql thanks to Hibernate, but something wrong with it, and i don't know what

**My controller:**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    private final IUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/user/create")
    public ResponseEntity<UserPojo> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        UserPojo result = userService.createUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserPojo> getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        UserPojo result = userService.getUser(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    private final Converter converter;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(Converter converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserPojo createUser(User user) {

        entityManager.persist(user);

        return converter.userToPojo(user);
    }
```

But when i ran it in Postman, i got this - I don't know why it appears:

[image]

**More info:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1449)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:488)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
```

My POM and more code is here:
[GitHub](https://github.com/HosakooD/ToDo)

Answer (score 0):

You have a weird and inconsistent mix of dependencies here

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When you use Spring Data JPA version 3.0.0 you should use Hibernate 6+. To get started you shouldn't specify the versions for Hibernate since those are specified in the Spring Data JPA `pom.xml`.

And you shouldn't need `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` at all.

Comment: HTH. The customary way to say "It works" is to accept the question. And to say "Thank you" you upvote the question. ;-)