# spring boot mysql - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErrorjavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to integrate with spring boot with mysql and have below dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Using below as reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mysql-tls

I am getting below error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","msg":"javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Followed few resolutions like.
[Type jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791432/type-jakarta-persistence-entitymanagerfactory-not-present)